# {%=file.name%} output inconsistency

Tags: php, html

I found a drag and drop file upload system and i want use this code on my website. And I must connect with database. But a problem occurred during integrated. My problem is;

```
<a id="aaa" href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>

$k = "{%=file.name%}";
echo $k; //output is: 4jkv1z2.jpeg
$sorgu="insert into images (image) VALUES ("{%=file.name%}");
mysql_query($sorgu); //output in table : {%=file.name%}
```

I can't get $k output in database. What can i do ?

Comment: I'm not sure that you have clearly outlined what the actual problem is. Any errors? Any inconsistent behaviour? Anything at all?

Comment: I want real image name in database. ("4jkv1z2.jpeg")

Comment: This does not look like `javascript` or `jquery` or `ajax`. So I have removed those tags. What extension/tool are you using that uses that syntax please.

Comment: The query syntax is wrong, so I have to assume you are getting an error message. Try looking in the php error log as a first step in your debugging process. Thats not a valid string as the double quotes do not match.

Comment: It might well be that you are writing PHP code and expecting it to be run on the browser. That cannot happen as PHP only runs on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your templating engine (whatever it is) is looking for the replacement pattern in the html output of your code, not the code itself, thus when you echo the variable it actually echoes the replacement pattern, that gets replaced, but the sql query never gets outputted, thus never the pattern never gets replaced.

What you are trying to accomplish is not possible in the way you are trying it, take a look at the documentation of the templating engine or framework you are using. There might (must/should) be other ways to access the variable before the replacement.